# Custom cases of product in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Setting a Magento store for a winery. They well bottles of wine, but you can only order bottles in cases of wine. There are 12 bottles of wine in a case, and you can make a custom case.

So user could pick 4 Chardonnay, 6 Merlot and 2 Shiraz to make a case of 12. But they could not just choose 4 Chardonnay and 6 Merlot. Orders have to be in multiples of 12.

Is there any way in Magento via default functionality or an extension to enforce this requirement in my Magento store?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen this specific functionality, but you could use a bundle w/ user defined quantities, with the addition of some custom logic for enforcing the multiples. This is likely to be your fastest path to getting this running.

Hope that helps,
Joe

---

EDIT: Resources on how to set up a bundle are a little slim on the internet. I did find [an old video from when bundles were released](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/magento-bundle-11/) that covers the basics.

The fast story is that you need to set up a bundle with items that are marked as "user defined qty", which will display a qty box for each block that is defined in this way. Then grab the inputs when the form submits and reject it if the quantities don't  add up to a multiple of 12.

Upon consideration, pricing bundles this way may not be trivial unless you are providing a consistent price for each bottle of wine. e.g. You cannot easily jump the price from 1-dozen to 2-dozen.

Comment: Joe, do you know where I can find some good documentation on allowing the user to setup bundle in the way I want? I did some searching but couldn't find anything too related to my example above. 
Once I get that working like you said it's a matter of some custom logic for enforcing multiples of 12. 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is what I call a "configurable bundle."  The base bundle product would be a case with 12 bottles.  You can then configure the bottles within the bundle.

There isn't a way to do this with Magento proper.  In my former position we tried doing this with custom apparel.  The base bundle product would be a blank shirt.  You would then try to configure the shirt with screen printing, embroidery, etc.

We ended up creating/managing a custom object within the cart.  We then had to write some custom pricing logic for the cart.

I know that this feature has been talked about for quite some time.